# Preload images with jCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I have the following code which loads a JSON feed and creates all the HTML needed for the jCarousel to work. However, I'm not sure how to preload the images. Anyone have any idea's how to do this?

```
$(".banner ul").jcarousel({
    itemLoadCallback:loadTopBanner,
    auto: 6,
    wrap: 'circular',
    scroll: 1,
    animation:1000,
    itemFallbackDimension:10
});

function loadTopBanner(carousel, state){
    $.getJSON("get_top_banner.php", function(data){
        carousel.size( data.length );
            $.each(data, function(i){
                carousel.add(i, makeTag(this.imageURL, this.URL));
            });
        });
    }

function makeTag(img, url){
    return "<a href='" + url + "'><img src='" + img + "'></a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* do the trick, however, it is untested, and can be further optimised:

```
function loadTopBanner(carousel, state) {
    $.getJSON("get_top_banner.php", function(data) {
        carousel.size(data.length);

        // make array of elements to which load events can be attached
        var imgs = [];

        $.each(data, function(i) {
            var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", this.imageURL);
            imgs.push(img);
        });

        // init a load counter
        var loadCounter = 0;

        $.each(imgs, function() {
            $(this).one("load", function() {
                loadCounter++

                // when all have loaded, add to carousel
                if (loadCounter == data.length) {
                    $.each(data, function(i) {
                        carousel.add(i, makeTag(this.imageURL, this.URL));
                    });
                }
            });
            if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", data.imageURL);` should be `var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", this.imageURL);` but apart from that, it works great.

Comment: @dotty - oops, you're right. Updated my answer with that. Glad it solved your problem!

Comment: Thanks again, this saved me a lot of head aches.

Comment: Just a follow up, this sometimes works in IE7 (and 8) but other times it doesn't. It seems the `.('load')` doesn't get called all the time, or perhaps the `this.complete` is not triggering it correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

May not be a good solution but you can try to load the images somewhere on the page in a hidden div so that they will get cached before you make a ajax call and use them in loadTopBanner method. This way the carousel will not show any delay in loading the images.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to preload images, you don't need to put them in a hidden div -- you can use the Image object:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "images/foo.jpg";
```